# Why does the Hurewicz homomorphism factor through the abelianization of the fundamental group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-verification

In my notes it's claimed that the group homomorphism $$\Phi: \pi_{1}(X,x_{0}) \to H_{1}(X), \space \{f\} \mapsto[f]$$
*clearly* induces a group homomorphism $\Phi_{*}: \pi_{1}(X,x_{0})^{ab} \to H_{1}(X)$. For this to hold we need $\langle f*g*f^{-1}*g^{-1}\mid f,g \in \pi(X,x_{0})\rangle \subset ker(\Phi)$.

**Question:**
Is there an easy way to see this other than computation? Maybe some intuition why this should be true or follows directly by some other reasoning? My computation is rather 'complicated' for something that should be somehow *clear*:

Consider $\sigma: \Delta_{2} \to X$ a 2-simplex with $f*g*f^{-1}*g^{-1}$ on th $[e_0,e_2]$ face, $f*g$ on $[e_0,e_1]$ and $f^{-1}*g^{-1}$ on $[e_1,e_2]$ and on the interior we are constant along the linesegments perpendicular to the edge $[e_0,e_2]$.

Then we obtain by computing the boundary:

$\partial \sigma=(f^{-1}*g^{-1})-(f*g*f^{-1}*g^{-1})+(f*g)$ 
$\iff$ 
$f*g*f^{-1}*g^{-1}=\partial \sigma+(f*g)+(f^{-1}*g^{-1}) $

We know by a previous lemma that $f*g-f-g$ is a boundary. So we get:

$$[f*g*f^{-1}*g^{-1}]=[\partial \sigma +f*g+f^{-1}*g^{-1}]=[f*g+f^{-1}*g^{-1}]=[f+g+f^{-1}+g^{-1}]=[f+f^{-1}]+[g+g^{-1}]=[0]=0_{H_{1}(X)}$$

where in the last step I used the fact that $f+f^{-1}$ is a boundary.

Comment: $H_1(X)$ is abelian. So the kernel of any group homomorphism to $H_1(X)$ contains the commutator subgroup of the domain.

Comment: Whoops I feel so dumb now, well thanks for the answer.

Comment: So maybe the real issue is why the Hurewicz homomorphism is a homomorphism.

Comment: Not really as I mentioned before we know that $f*g-f-g$ is a boundary, hence $$\Phi_{*}(\{f*g\})=[f*g]=[f+g]=[f]+[g]=\Phi_{*}(\{f\})+\Phi_{*}(\{g\})$$ That $\Phi$ is well defined follows from the fact that homotopic loops are also homologous.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just saying that's the somewhat non-trivial fact behind this result.

Comment: @DanielFischer You shouldn't answer questions in comments :( See what happened...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way to show that the group homomorphism $\Phi: \pi_1(X,x_0) \to H_1(X)$ induces a group homomorphism on the abelianization of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ by observing (as suggested by Daniel in the comments above) that $H_1(X)$ is an abelian group.

Hence $\Phi(aba^{-1}b^{-1})=0$ by using the homomorphism property and the fact that $H_1(X)$ is abelian. This implies that the commutator subgroup generated by elements $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is indeed contained in the kernel of $\Phi$.